# Access from cPanel to phpMyAdmin with 'Welcome to phpMyAdmin' screen

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

When I access from cPanel and click on phpMyAdmin, it pops up a blank page with the line "Welcome to phpMyAdmin" and i try to refresh many times but still the same

[phpMyAdmin blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVJML.png)

Has anyone encountered this error?

Comment: Can you get your php error logs? They should be located in /var/logs/apache2/error.logs or something similar to that... That would be a good place to look to start finding out what's going on - assuming you are running on some kind of nix OS.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of research, I found a solution to fix the blank page in this case.

In your WHM (cPanel), visit: SQL Services -> Manage MySQL® Profiles -> and in the "Actions" column, click on "Validate" and the problem will be resolved.

[Validate MySQL profile to fix phpMyAdmin blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJF4c.png)