# Apache, phpmyadmin, .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, phpmyadmin

I remembered that I customized some setting in .htaccess in /var/www/html on Ubuntu.

But when I access http://my_ip/phpmyadmin, it displays only 
Welcome to phpMyAdmin

And there is no login input.

What is the cause? How can I fix it?

Thank You

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHQ6W.jpg)

Comment: Here is my .htaccess
`
RewriteEngine on
Options  -MultiViews -Indexes
EnableSendfile Off

<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php|jsp|aspx|asp)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>

RewriteBase   /
RewriteRule   ^$ - [R=404,L]
php_flag display_errors off
`

Comment: smth like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699998/access-from-cpanel-to-phpmyadmin-with-welcome-to-phpmyadmin-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699998/access-from-cpanel-to-phpmyadmin-with-welcome-to-phpmyadmin-screen)